# Why does this function not work in php?

Tags: php, function

Here is my function,

It is meant to get the user level an the amount of xp needed until the next level, it works but only through levels 1 to 2, then if the required xp for level 3 is entered it fails.

The XP doubles per level, so from level 1 to 2 is 10, 2 to 3 is 20, 3 to 4 is 40 etc;

$user['xp'] is an int to explain better, here are some examples of what the function returns with different values.

1. $user['xp'] == 1, level 1, xpGot 1, xpNeeded 9, 10%
2. $user['xp'] == 5, level 1, xpGot 5, xpNeeded 5, 50%
3. $user['xp'] == 9, level 1, xpGot 9, xpNeeded 1, 90%
4. $user['xp'] == 10, level 2, xpGot 0, xpNeeded 20, 0%
5. $user['xp'] == 15, level 2, xpGot 5, xpNeeded 15, 25%
6. $user['xp'] == 29, level 2, xpGot 19, xpNeeded 1, 95%

**7. $user['xp'] == 30, level 2, xpGot 0, xpNeeded 0, 0%**
It fails there on after.

```
function calculateLevel($xpGot) {
    $level = 1;
    $xpNeeded = 10;

    while ($xpGot >= $xpNeeded) {
        $level++;
        $xpGot %= $xpNeeded;
        $xpNeeded *= 2;
    }

    if ($xpGot < $xpNeeded) {
        $xp = $xpGot / $xpNeeded * 100;
        echo '<p>Level: ' . $level . '</p>';
        echo '<div class="displayBarWrap" title="' . $xpGot . '/' . $xpNeeded . ' XP (' . $xp . '%)">
              <p>XP:</p>
            <div class="displayBar"><div style="width: ' . $xp . '%;"></div></div></div>';
    }
}

calculateLevel($user['xp']);
```

Comment: What is the value of `$user['xp']`?

Comment: how much xpGot should be for level 3? because the "%" operation is reducing the value of xpGot way lower than xpNeeded and hence the while loop only runs once never reaching level = 3. Not sure if that's what you want to do...

Comment: level 3 should be 10 + 20 + 40, so 70, it was because I using the modulus rather than minusing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want following: replace `%=` with `-=`:

```
$xpGot -= $xpNeeded;
```

Comment: This works, but what about if a user levels up 2 levels in one go, will it carry the division remainder over from each level up? That is what I was trying to implement with the modolus?

Comment: But it now fails if I got 1xp it throws everything into minus lol

Comment: My bad, was a typo seems to be working now, thanks, just testing it now further :)

Answer (score 3):

Take this line

```
$xpGot %= $xpNeeded;
```

There is no difference if the $xpGot is 15 or 45, `% 10` will still return 5. The modulus operator divides the left operand by the right and returns the remainder.

Changing it to `-=` as @scessor suggested is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

With the fix the others mentioned and a possible mistake in the echo, this works for me:

```
<?php
    function calculateLevel($xpGot) {
        $level = 1;
        $xpNeeded = 10;

        if ($xpGot < $xpNeeded) /* NEW! */
            return;

        while ($xpGot >= $xpNeeded) {
            $level++;
            $xpGot -= $xpNeeded;  /* FIXED (other answers!) */
            $xpNeeded *= 2;
        }
        if ($xpGot < $xpNeeded) {
            $xp = $xpGot / $xpNeeded * 100;
            echo '<p>Level: ' . $level . '</p>';

            /* FIXED ? */
            echo '<div class="displayBarWrap" title="' . $xpGot . '/' . $xpNeeded . ' XP (' . $xp . '%)"> <p>XP:</p> <div class="displayBar"><div style="width: ' . $xp . '%;"></div></div></div>';
        }
    }

    calculateLevel($user['xp']);

?>
```

Comment: Try it with a value of 1000, it won't go past level 2 for me, using wamp php 5.3.5

Comment: You need to use the fix posted by the others, too. `$xpGot -= $xpNeeded;`